# Is it still possible to install Unity?

Tags: unity, ide, installer, support

When trying to install Unity I am getting the following error:

> The download of version ... was cancelled.
>   [image]

I checked that there are no spaces in the path.
[image]

Also I can not Sign in.
When I provide the correct email and password the Sign in window just closes with no result.

Also I tried to report a bug using the Report Bug feature, but it seems not to work.
[image]

Also I tried to post a question on [Unity Forum](https://forum.unity.com/). But the Sign In over there does not work as well.

What else may I try? Thank you.

Comment: This looks like an issue that Unity's support team will be better equipped to help you solve than its userbase is.

Comment: @DMGregory, Thank you. But what method could I use to reach the Unity support team?

Comment: Here's a [walkthrough guide to reporting a bug to Unity support](https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/bug-reporting)

Comment: @DMGregory, it tells `When running Unity choose Help->Report a Bug...` the problem is that I cannot install Unity. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like your account might be corrupted in some way. Try using a clean browser (eg. in private / incognito mode) to create a brand new account on the Unity website, and see if you can sign in with that. Then you can use that new account to report a bug through the HUB or forum.

Comment: You can always download the installer directly. https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive

Comment: @EdMarty that looks like it's worth sharing as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Unity Hub is not working, you can still always download any version of Unity directly from their website:

https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive